# TicTacToe how to reset board when play again?

Tags: python

I have the list for my board outside of any functions and I am trying to reset the board when I want to play again. I have tried creating a separate function to reset the board to its original value and return the new board but I can't get it to work. I am trying to just reset the board to blank in the play_again function but it still will not reset the board to blank when I choose play again. I also tried making a separate function to copy the board with the deep copy operator and use at the start of the game although I was not sure how to implement it correctly.

```
graph = [[' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '],
     ['-','+', '-', '+', '-'],
     [' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '],
     ['-', '+', '-', '+', '-'],
     [' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' ']]




def draw_graph():
    for row in graph:
        for col in row:
            print(col, end = '')
        print() 


def play_game():
    again = 'yes'
    while again == 'yes':
        graph = [[' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '],
     ['-','+', '-', '+', '-'],
     [' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '],
     ['-', '+', '-', '+', '-'],
     [' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' ']]
        draw_graph()
        won = False
        current_player = 'player1'
        while not won:
            place_spot(current_player)
            draw_graph()
            won = check_win()
            current_player = flip_player(current_player)
        again = input("Do you want to play again? (yes/no) ")
    print("Thank you for playing.")
```

Comment: Why don't you make a simple array with 9 tiles and print the tiles borders when you print the board instead of putting the borders directly into the array ?

Comment: Lists are mutable objects. You already define the `graph` at the start of your program as a global. Just pass it as an argument to the functions and change the global graph directly, in-place

Answer (score 1):

It's a scope issue.

The `graph`defined inside the while block is *local* to the `play_game` function, it is shadowing the package-level `graph` variable, not changing it.

You either need to define `graph` as global in the `play_game` function, or (even better IMO) remove the package-level `graph` variable and pass the `graph` as an argument to `draw_graph` instead.

So this is how I would rewrite your program:

```
def draw_graph(graph):
    for row in graph:
        for col in row:
            print(col, end = '')
        print() 


def play_game():
    again = 'yes'
    while again == 'yes':
        graph = [[' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '],
     ['-','+', '-', '+', '-'],
     [' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '],
     ['-', '+', '-', '+', '-'],
     [' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' ']]
        draw_graph(graph)
        won = False
        current_player = 'player1'
        while not won:
            place_spot(current_player)
            draw_graph(graph)
            won = check_win()
            current_player = flip_player(current_player)
        again = input("Do you want to play again? (yes/no) ")
    print("Thank you for playing.")
```

Comment: This is *almost* right. Python only has a few kinds of scopes. In this case, the `graph` in the loop is local *to the `play_game` function* (not only to the `while` loop).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `draw_graph()` function with this should work:

```
def draw_graph():
    global graph
    for row in graph:
        for col in row:
            print(col, end = '')
        print()
```

You can also replace the code to make the graph variable defined within the function and also passed within it:

```
def draw_graph(graph):
for row in graph:
    for col in row:
        print(col, end = '')
    print() 

def play_game():
    graph = [[' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '],
     ['-','+', '-', '+', '-'],
     [' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '],
     ['-', '+', '-', '+', '-'],
     [' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' ']]
    again = 'yes'
    while again == 'yes':
        graph = [[' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '],
     ['-','+', '-', '+', '-'],
     [' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '],
     ['-', '+', '-', '+', '-'],
     [' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' ']]
        draw_graph()
        won = False
        current_player = 'player1'
        while not won:
            place_spot(current_player)
            draw_graph(graph)
            won = check_win()
            current_player = flip_player(current_player)
        again = input("Do you want to play again? (yes/no) ")
    print("Thank you for playing.")
```

Comment: Putting a `global` statement in `draw_graph` doesn't buy you anything, since that function doesn't try to rebind the global `graph` variable. It's the `play_game` function that tries to do that, so it's that one that needs the `global` statement (though as you suggest, using a local in `play_game` and passing it with an argument is probably best).

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood. The second one is probably the best option then.